# Data insertion and extraction in cache

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, caching

So i am trying to store sql row data into an array and then storing that array        into a cache .. and later extract the data from the cache .. How to do this using  php,mysql?
I want to store data array into a cache file and later extract.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $data[] = $row; }
```

Comment: Why use a cache _file_ and not a memory table? MySQL caches queries and their results in any case: maybe it is sufficient to have a large enough query cache.

Comment: What's the point of storing an already stored value ? You could "cache" it into a session variable but in your example (storing all the users) I don't see the utility.

Comment: dont use mysql_* functions

Comment: @Aurel that was just an example ... the data array actually contains some rules in my project ...

Comment: Please narrow down the criteria to store and access your data: How much storage you need, how frequently is it accessed in which way (for example one or many results), what is the ratio of data access to data refresh (because data changed) etc. There are multiple possible solutions, starting from generating a PHP include file via various database-dependent solutions to mechanisms like memcache.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $bar = 'BAR';
  apc_store('foo', $bar);
  var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));
?>
```

[An Example is given here on official site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)

[An Example is given here on official site that how to store array in cache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php#73560)

Answer (score 0):

You want to store that data in a file then?

If so, simply serialize the data and save it to a file on a location of your choice.

Look at these 2 functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $data[] = $row; } 


 $memcache_obj = new Memcache;


 $memcache_obj->connect('memcache_host', 11211);


  $memcache_obj->set('some_key', $data);

   echo $memcache_obj->get('some_key'); //for retrieval
```